# firebase save data and not overwrite it

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a database to save check-in and check-out times, But when using my code, the hours are overwritten instead of being saved one after the other. I have no idea how to do it

This is part of the code I'm using, but the problem is that the "input" field gets overwritten all the time.
My question is, does anyone know a way to save the data one by one, without overwriting it? Because the code works but I want to see all the input and output records. and I didn't find a way to do it.
I am using Kotlin as a programming language and Android Studio.

```
val dateStringEntrada = "${now.year}-${now.monthValue}-${now.dayOfMonth}" +
                    " ${now.hour}:${now.minute}:${now.second}"


db.collection("entradas").document(mail.toString()).update(
    "entrada", dateStringEntrada
)
```

[image: firebase and code in kotlin]

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling `update()` on the DocumentReference object, the `entrada` field will be updated (overwritten) each time you call `update()`. If you want to have multiple `dateStringEntrada` then you have to store them in a field that allows that. So to solve this, you should [store them in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) rather than in a string. If you however need multiple `dateStringEntrada` in different documents, then you can have the same `entrada` field with different values in multiple documents.

Comment: You're very welcome, Luigis. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: I can't find a way to solve the problem. But I'm still trying to find a way to do it.